# Why does my puppy go berserk when playing with plastic mugs?

Tags: dogs, toys

I have a month old puppy that I found abandoned on the street. Yesterday I gave it a plastic mug to play with. It went berserk and started trying to eat it. I tried the same with another coloured mug today, the same thing happened. Why is it behaving this way?
It first tries to enter the mug and then later becomes angry.

Answer (score 2):

Our pup loves to chew plastic containers, as the crackle noise they make is fun! Our friend has a Chocolate Lab who is obsessed with plastic soft drink bottles for the same reason. Also thicker plastics make a fun noise when they scrape against the floor.

On a note, dogs love to chew plastics as much as anything else, especially if their teeth are developing... Some grow out of it, some don't. Our old mongrel who passed a few years ago loved the plastics of yoghurt pots. Dogs explore with their mouth, so all different hardness and texture variations in fabrics etc for dogs is enticing, especially in the puppy stages.

For a dog so young the only reason I can see him getting frustrated is because it's so new and ideally, when not abandoned, at one month a puppy should be with its mother in a warm soft environment as he wouldn't normally have even finished weening at this age. So it might be that he's still unsure about what this mug is, how to play with it etc, and mum isn't there to show him.

You can actually (and we now have) purchase rubber bone toys which make the same crackle as plastic bottles our little guy loves it and it's a safer alternative to any plastics which may splinter when chewed.

Comment: Thank you, I was initially scared to even touch it when it started growling at the mug.The growling seemed like a big dog, but it later came running to me and started licking my feet lovingly.   So should I expect this for every plastic item?

Comment: @NikhilVandanapu he's super young so absolutely everything is new and learning. I find with our 4 month old pup if he's scared of something... If we play with it he understands it's not going to hurt him.

Comment: Remember, the growl may also be part of his game, "wrestling" with his toy.

Comment: I just wanted to note that it may not be as safe for the puppy to chew on plastic because of whatever chemicals are inside it, especially if the plastic comes from a different country with laxer food & health safety laws. Of course, your puppy isn't going to roll over and die if it chews on it, but it is probably safer to invest in chewables specifically made for puppies, like nylabones, or chewy treats such as dried sweet potatoes, etc (note that not all fruits/vegges are safe for dogs).

Comment: @rlb.usa yes that's why I meantiones as well rubber bones which crackle like plastic.